# Run specific method as a Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

In my code I have a main Class which is class **Client**. The class can have multiple readers of class **Reader**. A Reader needs to connect to the computer, then the Client has to wait for instruction from a server, and then the Client can run the Reader. Here are what I want to do:

1) Have a thread that check if all readers are connected, and if a reader gets disconnected that tries to reconnect it.

2) At the same time, get readings from active readers.

What would be the best way to achieve this ? Ideally my class would look like this:

```
public Class Reader implements Runnable{
    private boolean isConnected;
    public void connect(){
        ....
    }
    public String read(){
        ....
        return readings;
    }
}
```

However the method read() with a return is problematic. I would do something like this but this seems a bit messy to me:

```
public Class Reader implements Runnable{
    private int id;
    private boolean isConnected,isRunning;
    public String readings;

    public void run(){
        while(isRunning){
            if(!isConnected){
                connect();
            }
            else if(isRunning){
                read();
            }
        }
    }
    private void connect(){
        ....
    }
    private void read(){
        ....
        readings=...;
        // Client await()
        doneSignal[id].countDown();
        // Client reads readings here
        // When until signal from Client and sends countDown()
        readSignal[id].await();
    }
}
```

Is this way appropriate? or is there a more suitable way to do this (Executor)?

EDIT:
the layout of Client is the following:

```
public class Client {

// Variables.
private ReaderElement[] readers_;
private String serverAddress_;

public void run(){
    // I'd like to run this as a background thread to check if reader disconnect, and attemps to reconnect this occurs quite often
    connectReaders(); 
    // wait signal and available ports from server_Address_. Each reader connects to different port
    Map<Integer,Integer> listReaders=readStartSignal();
    assignPort(listReaders);
    //Readers start sending data to server. The connection can be very unstable.
    startReaders();
}

private void connectReaders()
{
    for (ReaderElement reader : readers_)
    {
        reader.connect();
    }
}

    private void startReaders()
{
    for (ReaderElement reader : readers_)
    {
        // Has to be modified to be run as different threads, now it only runs one reader
        runReader(reader);
    }
}

private void runReader(ReaderElement reader){
    // streams contrains in/out socket from/to server
    Streams streams = new Streams();
    streams.open(serverAddress_, reader.port_);
    try{
        readTags(reader, streams.in_, streams.out_);
    }catch ...
    streams.close();
}

private void read(ReaderElement reader, BufferedReader in, ObjectOutputStream out) throws ...
{
    String inputFromServer;
    String [] results;      
    while(!((inputFromServer = in.readLine()).equals("terminate"))){
            results=reader.read();
        }
        out.write(results);             
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: It reads them directly and shows them on the screen.

Comment: Ah, the Client methods also filter the data send them to the server, which shows them on the server screen (the shorter the delay the better). The screens show graphically processed data, which is performed by another class.

Comment: Iadded the rough layout of Client, in which I need to add separate threads for readers.

Answer (score 1):

> However the method read() with a return is problematic.

It is if your Reader class implements Runnable. However it does not necessarily have to. You can make it implement [callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). Now your "main" Reader method is no more `run()` but rather `call()`. Just make it return the return value of your `Reader.read()` method.

**Update**: moreover, implementing a callable may enable you to change the general behavior of your call method -- e.g. returning an informative exit value -- if your reader gets disconnected, leaving the management of such an event to the main/orchestrator class of your software.

Comment: The main problem was more on having to call two functions at separate time (first connect, then wait on server, then run). I find it weird to have a method just to fork to two other methods based on a condition. However I can proceed like in my example and return instead wait on signal.

Comment: you could make your connect method a blocking one. thus, your call method would just be something like `connect(); return read();` leaving the bulk of your logic to the "main" class.